# Scala timestamp/date zero argument constructor?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, squeryl

Squeryl requires a zero argument constructor when using `Option[]` in fields. I realized how I could create such a constructor for `Long` like `0L` but how do I create such a thing for a Timestamp or Date?

Essentially I need to finish this:

```
def this() = this(0L,"",TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP,0L,"","","","",Some(""),Some(""),"",DATE,DATE,false,false,false,Some(0L),Some(0),Some(0L))
```

Below is how I originally found the timestamp and date problem.

**Background**

Getting the following error in my Play! 2.0 Scala app (also using Squeryl):

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deduce Option[] type of field 'startOrder' of class models.Job`

This field in models.Job:

```
@Column("start_order")
var startOrder: Option[Int],
```

And in the Postgres DB it is defined as an `integer`. Is there different handling in Play! 2.0 of models, is this a bug, or is it a Squeryl problem? Thanks!

**Stack trace, looks like Squeryl problem**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deduce Option[] type of field 'startOrder' of class models.Job
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:66) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
        at org.squeryl.internals.FieldMetaData$$anon$1.build(FieldMetaData.scala:441) ~[squeryl_2.9.1-0.9.4.jar:na]
        at org.squeryl.internals.PosoMetaData$$anonfun$3.apply(PosoMetaData.scala:111) ~[squeryl_2.9.1-0.9.4.jar:na]
        at org.squeryl.internals.PosoMetaData$$anonfun$3.apply(PosoMetaData.scala:80) ~[squeryl_2.9.1-0.9.4.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:176) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `startOrder` is defined as

```
val startOrder: Option[java.sql.Timestamp]
```

in class definition. I believe,

```
Some(new java.sql.Timestamp(0))
```

should be passed to constructor.

Comment: Ah perfect, I figured `Some()` had to wrap it but I was confused on what it wrapped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Option* is used when a value is optional, i.e. if there could be a value or not. Only if there is a value, you use *Some* wrapping it. But if there is no value, you use *None*.